# How odd is a cluster of plane accidents?

Tags: probability, poisson-distribution

Original question (7/25/14):
Does this quotation from the news media make sense, or is there a better statistical way of viewing the spate of recent plane accidents?

> However, Barnett also draws attention to the theory of Poisson distribution, which implies that short intervals between crashes are actually more probable than long ones.
>
> "Suppose that there is an average of one fatal accident per year, meaning that the chance of a crash on any given day is one in 365," says Barnett. "If there is a crash on 1 August, the chance that the next crash occurs one day later on 2 August is 1/365. But the chance the next crash is on 3 August is (364/365) x (1/365), because the next crash occurs on 3 August only if there is no crash on 2 August."
>
> "It seems counterintuitive, but the conclusion follows relentlessly from the laws of probability," Barnett says.

Source: http://www.bbc.com/news/magazine-28481060

Clarification (7/27/14):
What is counter intuitive (to me) is saying that rare events tend to occur close in time. Intuitively, I would think that rare events would not occur close in time.  Can anyone point me to a theoretical or empirical expected distribution of the time between events under the assumptions of a Poisson distribution? (That is, a histogram where the y-axis is frequency or probability and the x-axis is time between 2 consecutive occurrences grouped into days, weeks, months, or years, or the like.) Thanks.

Clarification (7/28/14):
The headline implies it is more likely to have clusters of accidents than widely spaced accidents. Lets operationalize that. Let's say that a cluster is 3 airplane accidents, and a short period of time is 3 months and a long period of time is 3 years. It seems illogical to think that there is a higher probability that 3 accidents will occur within a period of 3 months than within a period of 3 years. Even if we take the first accident as a given, it is illogical to think that 2 more accidents will occur within the next 3 months as compared to within the next 3 years.  If that is true, then the news media headline is misleading and incorrect.  Am I missing something?

Comment: It makes sense. But I think what you should prefer to focus on is the expectation. Not whether the next crash is more likely tomorrow or the day after tomorrow.

Comment: Are you sampling without replacement?  If there is a 1/365 chance of a crash on every given day, then why would they interact?

Comment: Re the clarification: You might find it helpful to distinguish between *probability*, *probability per unit time*, and *expectation*. Although processes describing rare events will--practically by the very meaning of "rare"--have a long *expected* time between events, that is not inconsistent with the *probability per unit time* being greatest at the outset.  Nevertheless, the *probability* of the event next occurring within a short time will be very small.

Comment: @whuber: You capture what I see as illogical: "...a long expected time between events ... is not inconsistent with the probability per unit time being greatest at the outset."  I've tried to reword the clarification.  I would like to see if the distribution of inter crash times comports with your statement.

Comment: @JoelW.: I think the misunderstanding is this: What you're thinking about is the probability that a crash occurs "*within* the next three years" but I believe the article is in effect talking about the probability of the event occurring *in* three years. Also, since the events are clustering it means that there *will* be wide spaces where no event occurs...

Comment: Also, I just noticed this [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clustering_illusion)--you might like it. Oh, and I just came across this [pdf](http://www.mpia-hd.mpg.de/~calj/statistical_methods_ss2013/lectures/10_use_abuse_statistics.pdf), too--it specifically mentions the "clustering" of airplane crashes (and describes the issue much better than I have so far...).

Comment: Consider rolling a die. I've just rolled a '1' and I am about to roll some more times. If the rolls are independent, it's more likely that the *next* '1' comes on the very next roll than on any specific later roll (like say the 5th roll) - because for it to happen on that later roll, first an event with probability <1 must occur (no 1's were rolled), *then* an event with the same probability as '1 on the next roll'. That's all that's going on. Now consider slicing time up into (say) days, and look at "the next plane that crashes, crashes in the next day" vs "the next plane crashes on day 300".

Comment: @Glen_b: The flaw in the newspaper article (implied in the title of the article, which is the title of my posting) is that the article suggests there is a higher probability of a given number (i.e., a cluster) of accidents occurring in a short period of time than over a longer period of time.  That is just wrong.

Comment: The quoted part in your post looks correct.

Comment: Yes, the quoted part is statistically correct.  But there is a better way of looking at the spate of recent accidents: simply stated, it is unlikely to have such a spate in a short period of time.  It took some interaction with people here before it became clear to me that the news article reached the wrong conclusion despite correct statistical statements.  When I started this thread I did not have a clear understanding of why the headline was wrong.  So I reproduced the quote from the statistician.  It now seems the statistician missed the forrest while looking at the trees.

Comment: @JoelW.: If anything, it would be the *journalist* that screwed up... Anyway, is everything cleared up or do you still have any reservations left over?

Comment: My guess is that it was the statistician who misled the journalist.  I doubt the journalist got it wrong on his/her own (because it is so counter-intuitive).

Comment: The point is that the probability that the next crash is tomorrow is higher than the probability that the next crash is in exactly 366 days time, not because tomorrow is any more or less dangerous than the same date a year later, but because there is also the possibility that another crash may happen between now and then so reducing the probability that the *next* crash is in exactly 366 days time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Summary: The first sentence in the quoted BBC paragraph is sloppy and misleading.**

Even though previous answers and comments provided an excellent discussion already, I feel that the main question has not been answered satisfactorily.

So let us assume that a probability of a plane crash on any given day is $p=1/365$ and that the crashes are independent from each other. Let us further assume that one plane crashed on January 1st. When would the next plane crash?

Well, let us do a simple simulation: for each day for the next three years I will randomly decide if another plane crashed with probability $p$ and note the day of the next crash; I will repeat this procedure $100\,000$ times. Here is the resulting histogram:

[image: Distribution of plane crushes, a model]

In fact, the probability distribution is simply given by $\mathrm{Pr}(t) = (1-p)^t p$, where $t$ is the number of days. I plotted this theoretical distribution as a red line, and you can see that it fits well to the Monte Carlo histogram. *Remark: if time were discretized in smaller and smaller bins, this distributions would converge to an exponential one; but it does not really matter for this discussion.*

As many people have already remarked here, it is a *decreasing* curve. This means that the probability that the next plane crashes on the next day, January 2nd, is higher than the probability that the next plane will crash on any other given day, e.g. on January 2nd next year (the difference is almost three-fold: $0.27\%$ and $0.10\%$).

**However**, if you ask what is the probability that the next plane crashes in the next three days, the answer is $0.8\%$, but if you ask what is the probability that it will crash after three days, but in the next three years, then the answer is $94\%$. So, obviously, it is more likely that it will crash in the next three years (but after the first three days) than in the next three days. **The confusion arises because when you say "clustered events" you refer to a very small initial chunk of the distribution, but when you say "widely spaced" events you refer to a large chunk of it.** That is why even with a monotonically decreasing probability distribution it is surely possible that "clusters" (e.g. two plane crashes in three days) are very unlikely.

Here is another histogram to really get this point across. It is simply a sum of the previous histogram over several non-intersecting time periods:

[image: Histogram of plane crushes frequency]

Comment: Are you saying that the MIT professor is wrong?

Comment: No, the quote from Barnett in the BBC article is completely correct. But its interpretation by the BBC reporter is sloppy at best: *"Barnett also draws attention to the theory of Poisson distribution, which implies that short intervals between crashes are actually more probable than long ones"*. The most natural interpretation of this sentence is dead wrong (and I suppose Barnett did not mean to imply that). Maybe I should be more explicit about that in my reply. Is there any substantial part of my answer with which you disagree? Hope not, as I fully agree with yours.

Answer (score 14):

What the reporter is saying is that the random occurrence of a plane crash can be modelled as a *Poisson process*--a situation where the probability of an event occurring over some (small) interval is proportional to the length of said interval and where each occurrence in **Independent** of all others.

#### Is this a reasonable model for the scenario described?

Probably.

Sure, these events might not be *100% Independent* since other pilots likely alter their behavior (if only very slightly) after a crash. [I don't know--perhaps a few pilots do some extra bit of simulator training or something like that]. Nevertheless, the assumption of **Independence** is still entirely reasonable.

#### What about clusters of plane crashes?

Yes. Given a Poisson process (or even some other random process), you *would* expect to see some clusters of occurrences.

In fact, as described by the [Oxford Dictionary of Statistics](http://www.oxfordreference.com/view/10.1093/acref/9780199541454.001.0001/acref-9780199541454) in its entry for **Poisson Process** (which is a "mathematical description of randomness"):

```
[R]andomness usually gives rise to apparent clustering, despite the natural
expectation that randomness would lead to regularity.
```

---

For example, check out this simple bit of **R** code:

```
set.seed(123)
x <- runif(500)
y <- runif(500)

plot(x, y, pch=20, col='blue', main="A Random Distribution of Points")
```

which produces:
[image: Notice the clumping?]

Even though we *know* this is a plot of random points, it sort of looks like there are some *non*-random bits to it--specifically, in some parts of the graph there are clumps of points while other parts are wide open. It's this same sort of behavior that the article is trying to describe (only with **time series** data and not *spatial* data).

---

#### UPDATE:

@JoelW.: So, for instance, let's say the probability of a plane crashing tomorrow (or any day for that matter) is "**p**" (and, let's say "**p**" is something like 1 in a hundred).

The reason why the next plane crash is more likely to occur *tomorrow* than it is more likely to occur in exactly a year (i.e. on July 26, **2015**) is because the probability that the next crash is in exactly one year is equal to:

```
= Prob(crash tomorrow) * Prob(365 days with *no* crashes)
```

Make sense?

Ultimately, I think that the reason these things are Counter-Intuitive is because usually when we think of a phrase like: `"The odds of a plane crash in one month compared with the odds of one happening tomorrow"`. We naturally don't immediately consider the 24-hour period that begins in exactly one month. Instead, we (or at least I do) tend to think of it in more, well, *flexibly*. So more like: `a month ± a week`. That and the fact that we forget about taking into account the odds of a crash *not happening* in the interim... (But again, maybe that's just me...).

*Phew!*

---

#### Additional Resources:

- Wikipedia's article on the [Clustering Illusion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clustering_illusion)
- A [pdf](http://www.mpia-hd.mpg.de/%7Ecalj/statistical_methods_ss2013/lectures/10_use_abuse_statistics.pdf) which specifically mentions the "clustering" of plane crashes (on page 8) and briefly describes the mathematics of a **Poisson process**.

Comment: @Joel W.: Actually, I should add more to this answer--give me a couple minutes to edit...

Comment: "short intervals between crashes are actually more probable than long ones"

How is this different from saying that if there has just been a plane crash we should all delay our upcoming travel (for statistical reasons)?

Comment: The argument for delaying travel is the same one appearing in the old joke about how the TSA found a statistician with a bomb on board an airplane. When asked to explain herself, the statistician said "Well, the odds of one person having a bomb are small yet not small enough for comfort, but the odds of *two* people having a bomb are infinitesimal. Therefore when *I* bring a bomb, there is almost no chance there will be two bombs and we will be perfectly safe."

Comment: @JoelW.: Here's an analogy: Suppose you roll a die. Now, the probability that you roll your first "6" on your very first roll is higher than the probability that your first "6" comes on the 10th roll (or any other roll for that matter). You with me so far?

Comment: Your joke is on point, @whuber, but there seems to be some sort of logical disconnect between saying that "short intervals between crashes are actually more probable than long ones" and saying that the probability of a crash tomorrow is independent of whether a crash occurred today.  I guess probabilty can be counter-intuitive.

Comment: @Steve S: I follow your logic about rolling your first 6 on the first or on a subsequent roll, but how is that relevant to the plane crashes?

Comment: @JoelW.: For one, the example given by the journalist (as described by the professor) is actually of the **geometric distribution** (*not* the Poisson distribution), which is really easily described via the example of rolling dice.

Comment: Also, did you see that final section of my answer (The part that starts with the "Update" heading)?

Comment: Which part is counterintuitive? Prob(Plane crashes tomm| plane has crashed today) = P(plane crashes between t=0 and t=24) = 1-exp(-$\lambda$t) where $\lambda$ is the rate constant. The second statement says P(plane crashes in short time)>P(not crash in short time says) 1-exp(-$\lambda$t1)>exp(-$\lambda$t1). I am confused as to what the question is

Comment: @Sid: It makes sense when framed in mathematical terms (for those that understand the math, at least). However, I think the "Counter-intuitive" part is really referring to the *visceral* reaction many people get when they hear that "short intervals between crashes are actually more probable than long ones"--it may make sense when you analyze it more closely but (for a lot of people, at least) it doesn't (initially) *sound* right...

Comment: What is counter intuitive (to me) is saying that rare events tend to occur close in time. Intuitively, I would think that rare events would not occur close in time. Am I the only one with that intuitive view?

Comment: That's why it's so important to formulate these things mathematically instead of relying on intuition. And that's especially true with probability since we (i.e. humans) are pretty bad at thinking "probabilistically"...

Comment: @Steve S: Can you, or anyone, point me to a theoretical or empirical distribution of the time between events under the assumptions of a Poisson distribution?  (That is, the y-axis is frequency and the x-axis is time between 2 consecutive occurrences.)  Thanks.

Comment: @JoelW.: The [Exponential Distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_distribution).

Comment: @Steve S: Thank you for the link.  What would the exponential distribution look like for the assumed value in the news article (1/365)?  In any case, perhaps the Exponential Distribution does not address the headline of the article, which implies a comparison of the probability of a given number of events happening within a short time period with the probability of that number of events happening within a long time period.

Answer (score 4):

If the number of plane crashes is Poisson distributed (as he seems to be stating), the time between crashes has an exponential distribution. The pdf of the exponential distribution is a monotone decreasing function of time. Hence earlier crashes are more likely than later crashes.

Comment: "short intervals between crashes are actually more probable than long ones"

How is this different from saying that if there has just been a plane crash we should all delay our upcoming travel (for statistical reasons)?

Comment: Joel, That quotation is meaningless until its author quantifies what is meant by "short" and "long". In his example of an event with an expected rate of one per year, the chance of a recurrence during the next month will still be far less than the chance that the next crash occurs more than one year later. What he might have meant is that the *probability per unit time* is greater in the near term than in the longer term. To compare actual probabilities you have to multiply the probability per unit time by the duration (technically, you have to integrate it over the duration).

Comment: @whuber: The headline speaks of the probability of a cluster of airplane accidents.  Nothing said on stackexchange so far has convinced me that a cluster of airplane accidents is more commonplace or likely than widely spaced airplane accidents.  So, it seems to me that the quotation from the news media is downright misleading (perhaps because the time intervals are not identified, as you wrote).  What do you think?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "widely spaced airplane accidents" nor, for that matter, am I completely sure what you understand a "cluster" to be. Suppose, to make the situation concrete, a series of rare events occurs in years 0, 10, 11, 12, and 22 (counting from some initial date). Exactly how many "widely spaced" events have occurred? How many "clusters" have occurred? I can find defensible answers to the first question ranging from zero through ten and answers to the second question could be zero or one.

Comment: @whuber: The headline implies it is more likely to have clusters of accidents than widely spaced accidents.  Lets operationalize that.  Let's say that a cluster is 3 airplane accidents, and a short period of time is 3 months and a long period of time is 3 years.  It seems illogical to think that there is a higher probability that 3 accidents will occur within a period of 3 months than within a period of 3 years.  Even if we take the first accident as a given, it is illogical to think that 2 more accidents will occur within the next 3 months as compared to within the next 3 years.

Comment: @JoelW.: That was a good last comment--I think it really captures the discrepancy between your own take-away and what the prof. was trying to convey... Think of it this way: Let's say over the next five years there are five plane crashes. Now, if these plane crashes occur randomly then in all likelihood they *won't* be equally spaced in time (i.e. each one occurring a year after the previous crash). Instead, as a result of pure randomness, two or three of the crashes will appear "clumped" together. [Note: I think I may try to script a new simulation for this...]

Comment: @Steve S: I would like to see a distribution of inter crash times.

Comment: @JoelW.: Oh, you mean some sort of empirical distribution (i.e. some actual plane crash data)? ... I wouldn't be surprised if there was a built-in dataset somewhere... As far as Poisson distributed random variables go, there is a famous one (from back-in-the-day) looking at the number of German troops killed from getting kicked in the head by horses, analyzed according to battalion.

Comment: Data from a theoretial Poisson distribution would be fine. Is there a name for a histogram where the y-axis is frequency or probability and the x-axis is time between 2 consecutive occurrences grouped into days, weeks, months, or years, or the like?  In any case, having 3 plane crashes in a short period of time (as occurred recently) seems highly unlikely.

Comment: @JoelW.: You ever use Python? Because in this situation it may convince your intuition more just to run a few simulations (and I have a quick script using Python/Matplotlib)

Comment: Sadly, I have not used Python. But have run simuations from time to time (often in a cluster).

Comment: @JoelW.: So is the Exponential Distribution not what you're looking for?

Answer (score 0):

The other answers have already dealt with how *independent* events cluster. (Reading Gleick's Chaos, all those years ago, opened my eyes to this idea.)

But, in fact there is strong evidence that plane crashes are *not* independent events. [Cialdini's Influence](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0205609996) has a very good chapter on this (also mentioned [here](http://modeledbehavior.com/2009/12/17/do-suicides-indirectly-cause-plan-crashes/) which has a couple of links to data; and I found [an excerpt of that part of the book](https://fc.deltasd.bc.ca/~dmatthews/FOV2-00074762/S02DB0598.2/Cialdini%20airplane%20studies.pdf)). Obviously this is highly controversial: it is basically saying that the more publicized an air crash is, the more likely it is to influence a pilot (consciously or unconsciously) to crash his plane. But the psychological explanations underlying the hypothesis seem plausible, and the data seems to support it too.

(Links to statistics-based debunking research would be welcome, in the comments.)

Comment: Doesn't say that: says "immediately following certain kinds of highly publicized suicide stories, the number of people who die in commercial-airline crashes increases".

Comment: The reference for the claim is, I think, Phillips,(1978) "Airplane accident fatalities increase just after newspaper stories about murder and suicide", *Science*, **201**, pp 748-750. The abstract refers to "private, business, and corporate-executive airplanes".

Comment: Or perhaps this one: Phillips (1980), "Airplane accidents, murder, and the mass media: towards a theory of imitation and suggestion", *Social Forces*, **58**, 4, where "airlines" are mentioned in the abstract.

Comment: Altheide (1981), *Social Forces*, **60**, 2 suggests that a "certain kind of highly publicized suicide story" may not have been defined entirely independently of subsequent 'plane crashes - sounds rather like the definition of ["famous rabbi"](http://cs.anu.edu.au/~bdm/dilugim/torah.html).